# How to echo text file reader output in to the Jswing text pane?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java. My program is supposed to do the following:

Using the file browser, it will locate the txt file and then import it into the program using the `scanner` utility. It will then output the text content into the text pane.

I managed to write scanner code which reads the txt file and outputs the result to the console, and  I also created the interface to open the file browser, find the file, and get the file path as a string.

The problem is that I can't get the text output in to the text pane.

Code:

```
public FileChoosing() throws FileNotFoundException {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();fc = new JFrame();
    fc.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 500);
    fc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //fileChooser.setBounds(5, 11, 753, 243);
    fc.getContentPane().add(fileChooser);
    fc.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    JLabel lblFileName = new JLabel("New label");
    lblFileName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    lblFileName.setBounds(10, 25, 764, 30);
    fc.getContentPane().add(lblFileName);

    JLabel lblFilePath = new JLabel("File Path");
    lblFilePath.setBounds(10, 11, 764, 14);
    fc.getContentPane().add(lblFilePath);

    JTextArea jtextArea = new JTextArea();
    jtextArea.setBounds(20, 66, 618, 329);
    fc.getContentPane().add(jtextArea);

    final JFileChooser fc= new JFileChooser();
    int response = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);


    if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    lblFileName.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().toString());
    String fp = lblFileName.getText();
    File textFile = new File(fp);
    Scanner  in = new Scanner (textFile);
    while(in.hasNextLine()){

            String line =in.nextLine();
            //System.out.println (line);
            jtextArea.setText(line);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

the file Locator

[image: First window : File Locator]

The result should be shown inside the 2nd window:

[image: the result should be shown inside the 2nd window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java Strings are immutable. The problem is you are overwriting always the line variable `String line =in.nextLine();` and in the end you display only the last line.

One approach would be String Builder:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while(in.hasNextLine()){
                    String line =in.nextLine();
                    sb.append(line).append("\n");
                    //System.out.println (line);

            }

        jtextArea.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`setText` will overwrite the contents of your text area with the parameter you pass into it.

If you want to load the contents of the file into the JTextArea, you'll have to build up the string before using setText.

```
StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String line = in.nextLine();
    textBuilder.append(line);
    textBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator()); // nextLine doesn't return the line separator
}
jtextArea.setText(textBuilder.getString());
```